# Schedule babun script

Tags: cygwin, windows-server-2003, windows-task-scheduler

I need to execute a Babun script with Windows Scheduler on Windows Server 2003, the problem is: How can I execute a script in Babun shell from a `.bat` or similar?

The script is a really simple one line `rsync` command.

Here is the  [Babun](http://babun.github.io/) reference.

Comment: This question is about how to construct a command line to run a script under babun. This is not a `batch-file` question. Consult babun documentation. I would try `babun -h` or `babun --help` to see if it provided the answer.

Comment: Not sure this relates to cygwin either. Once you know how to start Babun and aim it at your script you should be good.

Comment: @Liturgist i already done that but it doesn't work. and there isn't documentation, and actually the babun shortcut on desktop call another executable whitout documentation (or i can't find docs on the web).

Comment: @AIG it is related to cygwin because there isn't a babun tag.

Comment: @Cronos - If you Right-Click on the babun icon and choose "Properties," What is in the edit control labeled "Target?"

Comment: If you search the web for `mintty man page` there are many results that describe all of the mintty options. http://mintty.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1127/trunk/docs/mintty.1.html

Comment: @AiG: Installing babun brings you a [preconfigured cygwin](http://babun.github.io/faq.html), so you kind of run inside a cygwin environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first copy `.babunrc` to `.babun_scheduler_rc` and add one line `export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"`

The location of `.babunrc` is: `C:\Users\user\.babun\cygwin\home\user` you can edit it from babun too.

next create the `script.bat`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set SCRIPT_PATH=%~dp0
set SCRIPT_PATH=%SCRIPT_PATH:\=/%
set BABUN_HOME=%SCRIPT_PATH%
set CYGWIN_HOME=%BABUN_HOME%\cygwin
set BASH=%CYGWIN_HOME%\bin\bash.exe

"%BASH%" -c "source ~/.babun_scheduler_rc && rsync -Crav /cygdrive/c/Path/To/Copy user@remote:/tmp/path/to/copy"
```

and now you can add it to the scheduler.